# CAGradientLayer not working in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, quartz-core, cagradientlayer

I did use `CAGradientLayer` to customize the UIButton in `iOS 5`, It worked fine for me and same thing to get Customized button and when I use the same code in the `iOS 6` it display me only `white` color on button ..is the `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` is not been supported by the `iOS 6`..
what would be reason its not displaying the customized button.
check the code it worked in `iOS 5`

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(pressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[button setTitle:@"START " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(62, 250, 196, 37);

[button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[[button titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Knewave" size:18.0f]];

// Draw a custom gradient
CAGradientLayer *btnGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
btnGradient.frame = button.bounds;
btnGradient.colors = 
  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:102.0f/255.0f green:102.0f/255.0f blue:102.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
    (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed: 51.0f/255.0f green: 51.0f/255.0f blue: 51.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] CGColor],
    nil];
[button.layer insertSublayer:btnGradient atIndex:0];

// Round button corners
CALayer *btnLayer = [button layer];
[btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[btnLayer setCornerRadius:5.0f];

// Apply a 1 pixel, black border around Buy Button
[btnLayer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
[btnLayer setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: You are implicitly relying on the order of the layers in the rounded rect button when adding your sublayer at a specific index. Since you are creating your own background and styling the text yourself, is there _any_ reason why you are not using `UIButtonTypeCustom`?